# Android Returning false onTouchEvent

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I read that:

**What are the touch event types?**

**The main ones are**

```
ACTION_DOWN - This is the start of a touch event. You should always return true for the ACTION_DOWN event in onTouchEvent if you want to handle a touch event. Otherwise, you won't get any more events delivered to you.
```

But when i return false for ACTION_DOWN, i get also ACTION_UP event afterwards. That shouldn't be happening.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

boolean flag = false;
Log.d("onTouch"," "+flag);
return flag;
}
```

Comment: That's interesting! Where did you get the explanation `ACTION_DOWN - This is the start of a touch event. You should always return true for the ACTION_DOWN event in onTouchEvent if you want to handle a touch event. Otherwise, you won't get any more events delivered to you.` ? I just tested it, and I realized that this is true with LinearLayout, but not with Button, as Button onTouchEvent always receive other event types `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_MOVE` even after returning false. Maybe Button (extends TextView) is a bit different for behaviors on Touch process.

Comment: Which type of View you're using? I'm trying to investigate on it

Comment: This onTouchEvent is on my Activity. So its the last that handles the events. So its logical to handle all the events. Problem Solved